# Linq XML - getting distinct values with the combination of parent node & child node

Tags: xml, linq, distinct, parent

I've made a Linq statement wish recieves all nodes of a XML file.

```
foreach (var node in epaXmlLoad.Root.Descendants()
                                    .DescendantNodes()
                                    .OfType<XElement>()
                                    .Distinct())
{
    newEntity = true;
    xmlModel.Node = node.Name.ToString();
    xmlModel.ParentNode = node.Parent.Name.ToString();

    model.Save(xmlModel);
}
```

This will save the Node and the parent of that node in a table.

But when I run this there will be duplicated data in the table.
I Can't distinct on the node value only because there are more child nodes with the same name but with other parent nodes above them.

```
<EPC>
<General>
    <Input>3</Invoer>
    <Amount>3</Amount>
    <Name>Bla</Name>
</General>
<Sectors>
    <Sector>
        <Name>Blalbla</Perc>
        <UsageID>0</UsageID>
        <Detection>0</Detection>
    <Sector>
    <Sector>
        <Name>Blalbla</Perc>
        <UsageID>0</UsageID>
        <Detection>0</Detection>
    <Sector>
<Sectors>
<Devices>
    <Device>
        <Name>Bladiebla</name>
        <Amount>5</Amount>
        <Detection>True</Detection>
    </Device>
    <Device>
        <Name>Bladiebla2</name>
        <Amount>5</Amount>
        <Detection>True</Detection>
    </Device>
<Devices>
```

^ This XML describes my problem.

Comment: Could you give **xml** example and desired output?

Comment: I've added it in the question

Comment: And what output is desired?

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is not very clear on the expected result it seems you are trying to remove duplicate nodes from the XML.

The XML:

```
<Parent>
  <Child>
    <Value>42</Value>
  </Child>
  <Child>
    <Value>stackoverflow</Value>
  </Child>
  <Child>
    <Value>stackoverflow</Value>
    <Grandchild>17</Grandchild>
  </Child>
  <Child>
    <Value>42</Value>
  </Child>
</Parent>
```

should be transformed into:

```
<Parent>
  <Child>
    <Value>42</Value>
  </Child>
  <Child>
    <Value>stackoverflow</Value>
  </Child>
  <Child>
    <Value>stackoverflow</Value>
    <Grandchild>17</Grandchild>
  </Child>
</Parent>
```

This requires a recursive comparison of the whole tree. Using `Distinct` on elements will fail since it doesn't take the children into account.

```
public static XElement Reduce(XElement root)
{
    XElement result = new XElement(root.Name);
    result.Add(root.Nodes().OfType<XText>());

    List<XElement> children = new List<XElement>();

    foreach (var child in root.Elements())
    {
        var reducedChild = Reduce(child);

        if (!children.Any(c => IsDuplicate(c, reducedChild)))
        {
            children.Add(reducedChild);
        }
    }

    result.Add(children);

    return result;
}

public static bool IsDuplicate(XElement element1, XElement element2)
{
    if (element1.Name != element2.Name || element1.Value != element2.Value)
    {
        return false;
    }

    var children1 = element1.Elements();
    var children2 = element2.Elements();

    if (children1.Count() != children2.Count())
    {
        return false;
    }

    return children1.Zip(children2, (c1, c2) => IsDuplicate(c1, c2)).All(isDup => isDup);
}
```

Calling `Reduce` on the root of your `XDocument` will build a new `XElement` with distinct elements. You can now add all nodes to your model.

Please note that this doesn't take attributes into account. Also be aware that this is probably not the most efficient algorithm for the job.

BTW: Your sample XML is full of errors (tags not closed properly).